Application can not authorize the client for reach the endpoint. Jwt bearer
I have a problem. I can generate jwt token in application thats ok. However when i add the authorize any endpoint, i get invalid token alert on postman. I have tried either headers or authorization tab on Postman. But problem is keep going.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = jwtSettings["Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = jwtSettings["Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key)
    };
});
——————
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


public TaskController(AppDbContext context)
        {  _context = context; }

        [HttpGet("gettaskdescription")]
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult GetTasksTitle(int id)
        {
            var tasks = _context.Tasks.ToList();
            
            var taskControl = tasks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

I think token is generated but can not send for authorize. Please help thank you.
Best regards

You should compare the key parameter with the key where you generated your token. You probably get the error because the key is different where you validate and where you generate.
